# Can Facebook ads be created in Social Studio

Tags: facebook, social-content, socialpost

I know that Facebook posts can be created and published from within social studio. Can a facebook add be created and published via Social Studio? If yes, can you please tell briefly how or direct me to a link where I can find relevant information?
Thanks heaps!